# Invalid input URL error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

During setup of my project in eclipse, I have facing this error in error logs:

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.jboss.tools.seam.ui/icons/seam16.png".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.FindSupport.find(FindSupport.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.find(FileLocator.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.getStream(URLImageDescriptor.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.getImageData(URLImageDescriptor.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.access$3(URLImageDescriptor.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor$URLImageDataProvider.getImageData(URLImageDescriptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.DPIUtil.validateAndGetImageDataAtZoom(DPIUtil.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.<init>(Image.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.createImage(URLImageDescriptor.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.ViewLabelProvider.getImage(ViewLabelProvider.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnLabelProvider.update(ColumnLabelProvider.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerColumn.refresh(ViewerColumn.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:946)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1025)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(StructuredViewer.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateItem(StructuredViewer.java:2159)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createTreeItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:840)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.lambda$0(AbstractTreeViewer.java:817)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.createChildren(TreeViewer.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.setExpandedState(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2459)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.FilteredTree$1.recursiveExpand(FilteredTree.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.FilteredTree$1.runInUIThread(FilteredTree.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob.lambda$0(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4213)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3820)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowViewHandler.openOther(ShowViewHandler.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowViewHandler.execute(ShowViewHandler.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ShowViewMenu$1.run(ShowViewMenu.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4428)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4238)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3817)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
```

Comment: This might be an update problem. Do you get the same error if you start Eclipse with a fresh workspace (`-data new_workspace_for_testing`)?

Comment: Hi,
It's strange that after switching to a fresh workplace this error did not come but there are still some errors like,
"Component descriptor entry 'wsadmin.xml' not found"
"Component descriptor entry 'cell.xml' not found"
"Component descriptor entry 'component.xml' not found"

And these all messages have some plug-in associated with them.

Comment: And what happens when you reset the perspective in your old workspace (_Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective..._)?

Comment: After doing this, it is now in sync with the errors in the new workplace.
Errors have been defined in the previous comment and there is one more error which says 
"context and dependency injection (CDI)1.0 and dynamic web module 2.5 cannot both be selected"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing `seam16.png` probably no longer exists in the **updated or uninstalled** `org.jboss.tools.seam.ui` plug-in but is still used in the user interface which is persisted.

In this case, switching to a new workspace (*File > Switch Workspace*) or resting the perspective (***Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective...***) should fix the error.

If other or newer errors occur, this has nothing to do with the missing PNG but might be caused by the same update. You can revert an update: in *Help > About Eclipse* click on the *Installation Details* button and see *Installation History* tab. But before that, a *Help > Check for Updates* would be worth a try.